# android changing the target OS

Tags: android

I have downloaded the Zxing barcode reader android project.
Now opened this source in eclipse . THe targetof the project is 4.0.3

Now i go to properties->android -> and try changing the target , its not getting changed
When i click OK nothing happens and target remain as 4.0.3

I tried to set this project as library as well. Here also same thing happening

I am able to change target for other my projects.

Can please tell what could be the reason for this behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check your folder, its .class file might be in readonly mode. please set it to normal mode & then you can change the target or other things.

Comment: i changed the .classpath file permissions

Comment: Yes it worked :) Thank you very much.I was really spending lot of time on it , i just mentioned the file name for future reference

Answer (score 1):

Right click on your project go to properties and select android and your target and also change it in manifest.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clear your project
2. Change in Manifest.
3. Go to Build path --> Configure you build path --> Libraries tab --> remove the current lib..

When you compile the next time it should take from the manifest.